# Counting population of membership groups in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I want to understand how users are coming to my website.

There is a table with entrypoint events. The columns are
1) date
2) entrypoint type
3) user id

I want an output like
Homepage only - 1m users
Homepage and search - 2m users
Search only - 1.5m users

What joins should I do to get this output?

Here is the code I'm starting with

```
select
    cast(date_parse(substr(sessions.datehour, 1, 8),'%Y%m%d') as date) ds
    ,entrypointtype
    ,user_id
from
    bizinsights.events_entrypoints_clientevents
where
    eventtype = 'Click'
    and cast(date_parse(substr(sessions.datehour, 1, 8),'%Y%m%d') as date) >= '2020-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate twice.  The following breaks things out by counts for homepage and search:

```
select ds, num_homepage, num_search, count(*) as num_users
from (select user_id, 
             cast(date_parse(substr(sessions.datehour, 1, 8),'%Y%m%d') as date) as ds
             sum(case when entrypoint = 'homepage' then 1 else 0 end) as num_Homepage,
             sum(case when entrypoint = 'search' then 1 else 0 end) as num_search
      from bizinsights.events_entrypoints_clientevents
      where eventtype = 'Click' and
            cast(date_parse(substr(sessions.datehour, 1, 8),'%Y%m%d') as date) >= '2020-01-01'
      group by user_id, ds
     ) u
group by ds, num_homepage, num_search
order by ds, num_homepage, num_search;
```

That is more than you are asking for.  Instead:

```
select ds,
       count_if(is_Homepage = 1 and is_Search = 1) as both,
       count_if(is_Homepage = 1 and is_Search = 0) as homepage_only,
       count_if(is_Homepage = 1 and is_Search = 1) as search_only
from (select user_id, 
             cast(date_parse(substr(sessions.datehour, 1, 8),'%Y%m%d') as date) as ds
             max(case when entrypoint = 'homepage' then 1 else 0 end) as is_Homepage,
             max(case when entrypoint = 'search' then 1 else 0 end) as is_search
      from bizinsights.events_entrypoints_clientevents
      where eventtype = 'Click' and
            cast(date_parse(substr(sessions.datehour, 1, 8),'%Y%m%d') as date) >= '2020-01-01'
      group by user_id, ds
     ) u
group by ds
order by ds;
```